# Remove outside array if there is 1 array in a array

Tags: php, arrays

My query returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => admin
            [admin] => 1
        )

)
```

In this case the array contains one array, so I want to remove the outside array:

```
Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => admin
            [admin] => 1
        )
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh, just

```
$innerArray = $outsideArray[0];
```

Comment: But how do count the arrays in the outside array?

Comment: `if (count($outsideArray)==1){ $innerArray = $outsideArray[0];};`